# Prove limit of a sum is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that, if $a_k \geq 0$ for large $k$, and that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$$ converges. Prove that $$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{j+k} = 0$$

I believe I cant write  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{j+k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}.$$  However, taking limit does not give me the answer.

Comment: The claim is false. Take $a_k = 1$ for all $k$: the series $\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k}$ does *not* converge.

Comment: Some info is missing.  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ diverges

Comment: Clem you beat me to it.  Seems he is still editing the question...

Comment: No, that is just bad edit of someone else... $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$ is supposed to converge by assumption

Comment: @ClementC. I think the condition $ \exists \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{a_k}{k}$ was also given, and he want to prove that $\lim\limits_{j \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{a_k}{j+k}=0$.

Comment: Now it makes sense. For the record, "Assume (1), then (2)" and "Assume (1), and that (2)" are two *slightly* different beasts. (To the people editing questions: be careful not to change the meaning...)